# Maior valor de uma lista c# com base na chave tendo valor duplicado

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class ClasseTeste
{
    public string chave;
    public int valor;
    public string acrescimo = "rng";
}
```

E com ela, criei o objeto:

```
ICollection<ClasseTeste> valores = new List<ClasseTeste>();
        valores.Add(new ClasseTeste("A", 1));
        valores.Add(new ClasseTeste("A", 30));
        valores.Add(new ClasseTeste("A", 50));
        valores.Add(new ClasseTeste("B", 20));
        valores.Add(new ClasseTeste("B", 20));
        valores.Add(new ClasseTeste("C", 10));
```

Gostaria do seguinte output:

```
[{"chave": "A", "valor": 50, "acrescimo": "rng"},
 {"chave": "B", "valor": 20, "acrescimo": "rng"},
 {"chave": "B", "valor": 20, "acrescimo": "rng"},
 {"chave": "C", "valor": 10, "acrescimo": "rng"}]
```

Procurei várias soluções mas todas usavam o first(), não sei como faria isso para retornar os maiores valores em caso duplicado.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Utilizando apenas linq

Agrupa por chave

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ClasseTeste>> valoresAgrupadosPorChave = valores.GroupBy(x => x.chave);
```

Seleciona todos que possui o maior valor do grupo

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ClasseTeste>> maioresValoresAgrupados = valoresAgrupadosPorChave
            .Select(x => x.Where(y => y.valor == x.Max(z => z.valor)));
```

Seleciona todos os valores dos grupos

```
IEnumerable<ClasseTeste> maioresValores = maioresValoresAgrupados.SelectMany(x => x);
```

Juntando tudo voce tera algo assim

```
List<ClasseTeste> resultado = 
            valores.GroupBy(x => x.chave)
            .Select(x => x.Where(y => y.valor == x.Max(z => z.valor)))
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.valor)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!